# With an 8 hour layover in Changi, can I do a free tour?

Tags: transit, tours, sin

I’m an Indian citizen with a US visa traveling from US to Singapore on United Airlines, and after 8 hours have another flight on Air Asia to Thailand. I’m wondering if I can do free tours from Changi airport?
If yes then do I need to collect my boarding pass first for Thailand to show the proof of connecting flight?

Comment: Apparently Singapore airlines used to offer this but it's been suspended because of Covid. I also doubt that your ticket would qualify since it sounds like two separate tickets. See https://www.singaporeair.com/en_UK/us/plan-travel/privileges/free-singapore-tour/

Comment: Singapore is a tourist friendly country. Your best bet is to go to the immigration counter and ask politely. The rules keep changing.

Answer (score 1):

The tours, which were suspended because of Covid, are back as of April 3rd. https://www.changiairport.com/en/airport-guide/facilities-and-services/free-singapore-tour.html has the details. (Note: the Heritage tour doesn't start until June.) All four tours look really good, and match up quite well with things I'd take a visitor to if we only had a few hours.

You need a layover of at least 5.5 hours and it has to line up with a tour you want to take. There don't appear to be restrictions like "your itinerary must be all one ticket". You do need a valid entry visa (since you are going to enter the country, after all) but that is not likely to be difficult. There's a detailed FAQ with links at the Changi page above.